# Объединение столбцов по уникальным значениям для создания панельных данных в Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Итак, есть два показателя: x1 и x2. Дан список фирм и значения этих коэффициентов за несколько лет. Нужно отобрать только те из фирм, которые встречались и в x1 и в x2.

Итак, исходная таблица:

**x1:**

```
  FIRM  2016  2017  2018
0    A     5     6     5
1    B     5     6     8
2    C     9     9     9
3    D     5     6     7
4    E     0     1     3
5    F     2     1     2
```

**x2:**

```
  FIRM  2016  2017  2018
0    B     4     5     6
1    D     8     8     5
2    A     1     1     1
3    V     3     3     3
4    N     5     5     5
5    M     9     9     9
```

Итак, встретились дважды фирмы A,B,D.
На выходе нужно получить данные в таком формате:

```
FIRM    YEAR    X1  X2
A   2016    5   1
A   2017    6   1
A   2018    5   1
B   2016    5   4
B   2017    6   5
B   2018    8   6
D   2016    5   8
D   2017    6   8
D   2018    7   5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** более гибкий метод для объединения списка DataFrame's:

```
items = [x1, x2]

res = (pd.concat([d.set_index('FIRM')
                   .stack()
                   .to_frame(f'x{i}')
                   .reset_index()
                   .rename(columns={'level_1':'YEAR'})
                   .set_index(['FIRM','YEAR'])
                  for i,d in enumerate(items, 1)],
                 axis=1)
         .dropna()
         .reset_index())
```

результат:

```
In [66]: res
Out[66]:
  FIRM  YEAR   x1   x2
0    A  2016  5.0  1.0
1    A  2017  6.0  1.0
2    A  2018  5.0  1.0
3    B  2016  5.0  4.0
4    B  2017  6.0  5.0
5    B  2018  8.0  6.0
6    D  2016  5.0  8.0
7    D  2017  6.0  8.0
8    D  2018  7.0  5.0
```

---

```
In [34]: res =  (x1.set_index('FIRM')
    ...:           .stack()
    ...:           .reset_index(name='x1')
    ...:           .merge(x2.set_index('FIRM')
    ...:                    .stack()
    ...:                    .reset_index(name='x2'))
    ...:           .rename(columns={'level_1':'YEAR'}))

In [35]: res
Out[35]:
  FIRM  YEAR  x1  x2
0    A  2016   5   1
1    A  2017   6   1
2    A  2018   5   1
3    B  2016   5   4
4    B  2017   6   5
5    B  2018   8   6
6    D  2016   5   8
7    D  2017   6   8
8    D  2018   7   5
```

Comment: В каком виде в таком случае загружать данные? в два разных DF ? Можно сразу уникальный способ добавить для Xn ?

Comment: @Max, oops, а в вопросе это был __один__ DF?? Я подумал что это два разных DF

Comment: Да не страшно, я могу и как разные DF это загрузить

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что если этому способу следовать и добавлять третий DF , то просто дописать
`.merge(x3.set_index('FIRM')
    ...:                    .stack()
    ...:                    .reset_index(name='x3'))` ? Или нет?

Comment: @Max, добавил более универсальный способ...

Comment: Как всегда, выше всех похвал, благодарю)

Comment: А как от этой задачи перейти к так скажем обратной. Когда у нас DF - это несколько Xn, за один год. А на выходе получить тоже самое нужно?

Comment: @Max, лучше задать новый вопрос с примером входных и выходных данных... ;)